# ngStyle not working in Angular

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular. I followed tutorial at - [Angular 2 Component Interaction - Extended Components Example](https://angular-university.io/lesson/angular2-components-component-interaction)

I am trying to change the color of text by clicking on color options. Here is what I have in app.component.ts -

```
     import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component ({
    selector:'my-app',
    template:`<div class='color-picker'>
    <div class="color-title" [ngStyle]="{'color':color}">Pick a color</div> 
    <div class='color-picker-wrp'>
    <div class='color-sample color-sample-blue' (click)="choose('blue')" ></div>
    <div class='color-sample color-sample-red' (click)="choose('red')" ></div> 
    </div>

</div>`
,
styleUrls:['picker.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
   @Input()
   color:string;

   @Output("color")
   colorOutput = new EventEmitter();

   choose(color:string) 
   {     
    this.colorOutput.emit(color);
    console.log(color);
   }
}
```

I have created a plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/ryvw9W220EvLxMSqCCh8?p=preview

The color is not applied to the title - Pick a color, however it is logged in console properly.
After reading related articles, I could not make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to change color of text `Pick a color` on click of colored div so change `choose` function as below :

```
choose(color:string) {     
  this.colorOutput.emit(color);
  this.color= color;
  console.log(color);
}
```